# How do I grab records from today using ampscript?

Tags: ampscript, dataextensions, datetime

I am trying to check what records in a data extension are from today.

The data that is in the date field, 'localtime', looks like this:

> Thursday, November 01, 2018 10:07 PM
>
> Friday, November 02, 2018 09:00 AM

I try to find if a record, based on mobile phone, already exist in a data extension for today:

```
var @today, @checkExist, @existsAlready
set @today = FormatDate(now(1),"YYYY-MM-DD")
set @checkExist = 
LookupRows(@MYDataExtension,'mobile',@Mobile,'localtime',@today)

IF (RowCount(@checkExist) >= 1) THEN
set @existsAlready = 'true'
else then set @existsAlready = 'false'
endif
```

It just gives me "false" even if there are records from today,
Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is looking for a solution, I solved it using "Datediff". So, looping through all records and comparing todays date with the date of the record. If the difference between the dates is less than 1 day, then it is a record from today.

```
set @diff = DateDiff(@date_on_record,@Today1, 'D')

 if @diff < 1 then
 set @less_than_1_day = 'true'
 else then set @less_than_1_day = 'false'
 endif
```